# @Id from a @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE) concatenated with a String

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to map a legacy database table which has some weird primary key generated from a sequence concatenated with a static String.

An Oracle Sequence generates the ID as per the norm'. but the ID Column of the table in question is a concatenation of that sequence number and a String `AA`. Is it possible to use JPA to create the ID value in that same format when persisting new objects?.

The Oracle Sequence generates incremental numbers, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4 ... etc..

The Id of the table needs to be `AA_1`, `AA_2`, `AA_3`, `AA_4` ... etc..

I understand how to create an ID from a sequence by annotating the id field in the class and I assume I need to write my own bespoke ID generation class which gets the sequence and conatenates the `AA` String on to it.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own custom identifier generator by extending the IdentifierGenerator interface.

This can then use the Oracle sequence to get your value and then perform the concatenation.

You can then specify your generator class in your mappings.

Comment: Many thanks Alex, I did it slightly differently and wrapped the concreate SequenceGenerator implementation of the IdentifierGenerator in an abstract impl of the PersistentIdentifierGenerator. I then just extend that for a specific prefix. I then annotate my